# Filtering of a list during construction

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to filter a list of Azure locations to pick out the primary ones; primary location in this sense is the first location of a region pair that is in the list e.g. given a list `[ 'westeurope', 'northeurope' ]` the resulting list should be `[ 'westeurope' ]`.

So to solve this in the general case, I need to look at the partially generated new list to see if the current value's pair is already present and I can't come up with a syntax/method that works.

The only hack I have is something like this...

```
locals {
  pairs = {
    # Europe
    northeurope        = "westeurope"
    westeurope         = "northeurope"

    # UK
    uksouth            = "ukwest"
    ukwest             = "uksouth" 

    # Plus lots more ignored for brevity
  }

  # Just filter even indicies
  primaries = [ for x, index in var.locations : x if index / 2 = 0 ]
}
```

But it requires that the items in the correct order i.e. would work for `[ 'westeurope', 'northeurope', 'uksouth', 'ukwest' ]` but would provide an incorrect response for `[ 'westeurope', 'uksouth', 'northeurope', 'ukwest' ]`

Here's a table showing var.locations and the expected results for the different scenarios...

| var.locations | primaries |
| --- | --- |
| [ 'westeurope' ] | [ 'westeurope' ] |
| [ 'northeurope' ] | [ 'northeurope' ] |
| [ 'westeurope', 'northeurope' ] | [ 'westeurope' ] |
| [ 'northeurope', 'westeurope' ] | [ 'northeurope' ] |
| [ 'westeurope', 'uksouth', 'northeurope' ] | [ 'westeurope', 'uksouth' ] |
| [ 'westeurope', 'northeurope', 'uksouth' ] | [ 'westeurope', 'uksouth' ] |

Comment: Can you show what is the `var.locations` ... from your question all you need is the first element in an array `var.locations[0]` should do just that (assuming that var.locations is an array)

Comment: maybe add a few different inputs and the expected output